# cant print images (.svg) of folder using matrix

Tags: php

just print the square but not the image, dont know what is wrong, doesnt throw mistake.
Thanks

```
echo "<img src=\"img/$numero[$i].svg\" alt=\"$numero[$i]\" title=\"$numero[$i]\" width=\"140\" height=\"140\">\n";
```

Comment: Well, what does it ouput to the browser? Is it what you expected?

Comment: this one `echo '<img src="img/' . $numero[$i] . '.svg" alt="' . $numero[$i] . '" title="' . $numero[$i] . '" style="width: 140px; height: 140px">';`?

Comment: doesnt work , the lines are into for

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong in your code. Check if you have correct svg image or not at particular location. (inspect using chrome developer tool)

Check using Object tag or if your browser support or not. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to not mix strings with code vars. Always do proper concatenation:

```
 $str = '<img src="/img/' . $numero[$i] . '.svg"';
 $str .= ' alt="' . $numero[$i] . '"';
 $str .= ' title="' . $numero[$i] . '"';
 $str .= ' width="140" height="140">'. "\n";
 echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seem right, try checking if the svg image is in the correct image path you placed

i tested with this and is working well

```
<?php
    $numero = array('imagename', 'image alt', 'title');
    echo "<img src=\"Images/$numero[0].svg\" alt=\"$numero[1]\"   title=\"$numero[2]\" width=\"140\" height=\"140\">\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all, I discovered that it happened

I was missing a bar in front of the img

```
echo "<img src=\"/img/$numero[$i].svg\" alt=\"$numero[$i]\" title=\"$numero[$i]\" width=\"140\" height=\"140\">\n";

instead of

echo "<img src=\"img/$numero[$i].svg\" alt=\"$numero[$i]\" title=\"$numero[$i]\" width=\"140\" height=\"140\">\n";
```

I do not see any sense